# Why is my Datatables search function requiring at least two characters even i don't want it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am having a strange problem. My datatables search requires at least two characters. How can i remove this threshold? This is the only thing i changed.

```
$('.table1').DataTable({
        "aLengthMenu": [[2, 5, 7, -1], [2, 5, 7, "All"]],
        "iDisplayLength": 2
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery DataTables: Delay search until 3 characters been typed OR a button clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548893/jquery-datatables-delay-search-until-3-characters-been-typed-or-a-button-clicke)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i want exactly opposite of the linked question?

Comment: So, what threshold you want it to be?

Comment: Try just to change `if(this.value.length >= 3 || e.keyCode == 13) {` for `if(this.value.length >= 1) {` in the answer @GuruprasadRao linked.

Comment: This also is the answer given by [Datatables.net](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/714/minimum-characters-in-filter)