# How to implement delayed searching in datatables in Shiny

Tags: r, datatable

I have been having trouble with datatable searches triggering while a user is typing in a search term, even when delaySearch is working. The search triggers for the first character which is typed in, which can be very slow if there are large numbers of records. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548893/jquery-datatables-delay-search-until-3-characters-been-typed-or-a-button-clicke/23897722#23897722) for datatables, but I'm not sure how to implement it for R Shiny.

```
dt_options <- list(autowidth = TRUE, 
                   searchDelay = 1000 ) 

datatable(initial_list_df, 
          filter = list(position = "top",
                        clear = TRUE,
                        plain = FALSE ), 
          options = dt_options )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Apologies, have now added an MRE. Thanks for the suggestion, but I would like to avoid users pressing enter and instead search when they reach 3 characters