# DataTable Enter Key to Search

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables-1.10

I have tried

```js
search: {
  return: true
}
```

But it is not working in my DataTables version 1.10.15

I want to disable the auto search on each letter entering in the search field. Instead of that enter all the characters and hit enter button then only need to display the search results.

I am using an AJAX call to populate the search. So entering each letter executing a MySQL query in the backend.

Comment: You need a debounce. Only query if the user stops typing for i.e. 500 ms. **Update:** I added some useful links below. You should probably use the `searchDelay` feature.

Comment: The following question might be helpful: [jQuery DataTables: Delay search until 3 characters been typed OR a button clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548893/jquery-datatables-delay-search-until-3-characters-been-typed-or-a-button-clicke). Also, check out the [Docs: searchDelay](https://datatables.net/reference/option/searchDelay). Finally, there is already [discussion on this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/63420/delay-in-server-side-search-query) at the official forum.